# Images not aligning properly in table row but text is

Tags: html, alignment, html-table

I've got a very simple table with images I am trying to horizontally align. The text in the same row is aligning properly but the img is not. My HTML code is

```
       <td><td class="auto-style2" style="text-align: center;">
        <p><img alt="" src="http://www.launchpointsecurity.com/image/data/L7000.jpg" style="width: 75px; height: 60px;" /></p>

        <p><strong>Control Panel</strong></p>
        </td>
```

and my CSS is

```
.auto-style2 {
text-align: center;
border-width: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Pretty straight forward code, can't figure out for the life of my why its not aligning the image properly.

A live example can be seen at https://www.launchpointsecurity.com/index.php?route=bestblog/article&blog_article_id=1

Comment: The link you included in your post seems broken. It gives me a fatal error on Chrome. Can you include a picture in your post or replace the link?

Answer (score 0):

I Tested your code in jsfiddle and I see the img is centered.

```
check here: https://jsfiddle.net/dquinonez/mvcd3sos/
```

Comment: I wonder why a webbrowser isn't parsing it correctly then...? It shows up right on the blogs WYSIWYG editor also but when loaded via IE or Chrome it isn't centered.

Comment: Please add the code you wrote, in your post, and edit it so that we're able to click your link. Thanks.